# Getting a DataTemplate from a ResourceDictionary with a DataTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, resources, datatemplate, resourcedictionary, datatemplateselector

Currently I'm using a DataTemplateSelector to find the DataTemplates in my UserControl.Resources, but I want to move them into a ResourceDictionary. How can I look in a ResourceDictionary from a DataTemplateSelector?

Here's my current DataTemplateSelector:

```
    public class SettingsDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is Setting)
        {
            Setting registeritem = item as Setting;

            if (registeritem.EditValueVar.EditType == EditType.Textfield)
                return element.FindResource("TextboxDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else if (registeritem.EditValueVar.EditType == EditType.DropDown)
                return element.FindResource("ComboDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else if (registeritem.EditValueVar.EditType == EditType.Slider)
                return element.FindResource("SliderDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(registeritem.EditValueVar.EditType.ToString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your `DataTemplate` in a separated `ResourceDictionary`then add it to `App.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>        
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MyDataTemplate.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

In your `DataTemplateSelector` you can get your template by:

```
Application.Current.FindResource("myCustomDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
```

where `myCustomDataTemplate` is the key of the datatemplate you've specified in `MyDataTemplate.xaml` file.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a `ResourceDictionary` property to your `DataTemplateSelector` class:

```
public class SettingsDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public ResourceDictionary ResourceDictionary { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (element != null && item != null && item is Setting)
        {
            Setting registeritem = item as Setting;

            if (registeritem.EditValueVar.EditType == EditType.Textfield)
                return ResourceDictionary["TextboxDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            else if (registeritem.EditValueVar.EditType == EditType.DropDown)
                return ResourceDictionary["ComboDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            else if (registeritem.EditValueVar.EditType == EditType.Slider)
                return ResourceDictionary["SliderDataTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(registeritem.EditValueVar.EditType.ToString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

...that you set in your XAML:

```
<local:SettingsDataTemplateSelector x:Key="selector">
    <local:SettingsDataTemplateSelector.ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
    </local:SettingsDataTemplateSelector.ResourceDictionary>
</local:SettingsDataTemplateSelector>
```